# MySQL query to group results by date range?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I got a system that pings to the database every 2 to 5 seconds when he is connected the application. Depending on his connection, the ping timeframe can be bigger, like 10 seconds or so.

Example:

```
Pings: 1,4,6,8,9,12,16,20,50,180,187,189,200,203,206,210 ...
```

I want run a query to grab ranges that does not exceed 1 minute between the pings, group them, so I can tell for how long the user has been connected, and save into a new table like:

```
Connections table:
user: X | start_date: 1   | end_date: 50  | duration: 49
user: X | start_date: 180 | end_date: 210 | duration: 30
```

Since the pings from ,50,180, ... that exceeded 1 minute, where disconsidered by the query groups.

The pings are stored as timestamp, so can be easily converted to date, and the range from the last ping to the first one will give me the session duration.

Is there anyway to do it in a MySQL query? Any help?

EDIT: Adding ping history schema

```
id  int(11)
user_id int(11)
ping_timestamp  int(11)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show what your ping history table looks like?

Comment: id int(11) | user_id int(11) | ping_timestamp int(11) ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubled your given sample data to show how it works with multiple userIds.

See it working live in an sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c494a/5/0).

```
select
userid, groupnum,
min(ping) as start_date,
max(ping) as end_date,
max(ping) - min(ping) as duration
from (
select
*,
@groupnum := if(@prevUser != userId, @groupnum + 1, @groupnum),
@groupnum := if(ping - @prevTS > 60, @groupnum + 1, @groupnum) as groupnum,
@prevUser := userid,
@prevTS := ping
from
Table1 t
, (select @groupnum:=1, @prevTS:=NULL, @prevUser:=NULL) vars
order by userid, ping
) sq
group by userid, groupnum
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the data is inserted into the table in chronological order, which is the natural case http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c494a/2

Comment: @rsanchez True, minor mistake, already corrected. Feel free to remove the downvote :) and thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I'm going to setup a cron to read this table every 10 minutes, and move all expired pings groups (longer than 60 seconds), to a new table. So I can keep the ping table as memory type and only save final results, on a second table, how your query print them. The problem, is I need select, insert and delete the selected results, from that ping table. Is it possible to do? Could you help me how to proceed? Thanks in advanced! @fancyPants

Comment: @Henrique Sure, but I don't get what's the problem so far. You'll have to explain in more detail and it sounds like it's better suited as a new question. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I reposted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061452/mysql-query-to-select-insert-and-delete-selected-rows ... I appreciate your help @fancyPants

Answer (score 4):

Try this on your data:

```
set @rnum = 1;
select user_id
     , min(ping_timestamp) start_date
     , max(ping_timestamp) end_date
     , max(ping_timestamp)-min(ping_timestamp) duration
  from ( select user_id
              , ping_timestamp
              , @rnum := if(ping_timestamp - @prev_ping_ts > 60, @rnum+1, @rnum) rnum
              , @prev_ping_ts := ping_timestamp
           from test2
          order by user_id, ping_timestamp
       ) t
 group by user_id, rnum
;
```

Comment: You should initialize `@prev_ping_ts` as well.