# MySQL query to Select -> Insert and Delete selected rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, subquery

I got a system that pings to the database every 2 to 5 seconds, when an user is connected the application. Depending on his connection, the ping timeframe can be bigger, like 10 seconds or so.

Example:

```
Pings: 1,4,6,8,9,12,16,20,50,180,187,189,200,203,206,210 ...
```

I'm running a query to grab ranges that does not exceed 1 minute between the pings, group them, so I can tell for how long the user has been connected:

Here is the query I'm running to select the results, as advised by @fancyPants on this question:
[MySQL query to group results by date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925381/mysql-query-to-group-results-by-date-range/18984304?noredirect=1#comment28171641_18984304)

```
select
userid, groupnum,
min(ping) as start_date,
max(ping) as end_date,
max(ping) - min(ping) as duration
from (
select
*,
@groupnum := if(@prevUser != userId, @groupnum + 1, @groupnum),
@groupnum := if(ping - @prevTS > 60, @groupnum + 1, @groupnum) as groupnum,
@prevUser := userid,
@prevTS := ping
from
Table1 t
, (select @groupnum:=1, @prevTS:=NULL, @prevUser:=NULL) vars
order by userid, ping
) sq
group by userid, groupnum
```

Producing the following results:

```
user: X | start_date: 1   | end_date: 50  | duration: 49
user: X | start_date: 180 | end_date: 210 | duration: 30
```

I need help, adding to this query, an statement that will do the following.

1st. Insert the selected rows into a new table with the excatly same schema the query returns:

```
id: auto_increment| user: X | start_date: 1   | end_date: 50  | duration: 49
id: auto_increment| user: X | start_date: 180 | end_date: 210 | duration: 30
```

2nd. Delete the selected rows, that were selected on the query and inserted into the new table.

- This query will be run by a cronjob on the server, every 10 minutes. So I can clean the ping table, that will be heavily hit, and store into a new one the values that we are going to display to our surfers.
- On the new query, I need a clause to filter non expired pings. Non expired pings, are the ones done no longer than 60 seconds before the current time when the cron runs. For example, if now = 100, the last ping to grab can not be less than 41. This way, when the cron runs, I don't select the rows from the users that are still pinging to the database.

Can it be done in one query, or will I need two?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you only want to be able to report total duration of connection?  Are you trying to detect separate connections?

Comment: Yes to both. Detect separate connections and duration of each connection. Wanna move the groups to a new table, for optimisation purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(following up on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985070/2811448))
What exactly is stored in the ping_timestamp column? Unix timestamp or something else? I will assume it is unix timestamp.

Create the table that will hold the user activity data:

```
create table user_activity (
    user_id    int(11) not null
  , start_date int(11) not null
  , end_date   int(11) not null
  , duration   int(11) not null
);
```

Aggregate the data skipping the intervals that are not closed yet:

```
set @rnum = 1;
set @cut_off = unix_timestamp() - 60;

insert
  into user_activity
select user_id
     , min(ping_timestamp) start_date
     , max(ping_timestamp) end_date
     , max(ping_timestamp)-min(ping_timestamp) duration
  from ( select user_id
              , ping_timestamp
              , @rnum := if(ping_timestamp - @prev_ping_ts > 60, @rnum+1, @rnum) rnum
              , @prev_ping_ts := ping_timestamp
           from ping_data
          order by user_id, ping_timestamp
       ) t
 group by user_id, rnum
having end_date <= @cut_off
;
```

After that we can delete the processed rows based on the data in the user_activity table:

```
delete t
  from ping_data t
  join ( select user_id
              , max(end_date) max_timestamp
           from user_activity
          group by user_id
       ) ua
    on t.user_id = ua.user_id
 where t.ping_timestamp <= ua.max_timestamp
;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. The only problem, I still need a solution is how to SELECT only pings groups that are expired? Expired pings are the ones, that is not added to the database for the last 60 seconds. Grouping them is working fine, but if I run a cron to move these groups into a new table every 10 minutes, if an user remains connected for like 1 hour, it will shows up on the report table like: 0:00 - 0:10 / 0:10 - 0:20 / 0:20 - 0:30 and so on ... The correct would be, moving this group, only when the user disconnects, resulting into the report table: 0:00 / 0:60. @Dmitry S

Comment: My second concern is to delete, only the moved pings groups. If I run delete where ping_timestamp <= @cut_off - 60, I will be deleting non moved pings, from users that are still pinging to the database.

Comment: Ah, see your point now. I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Perfect! I will let it running and in case I run into any problems I will let you know. But from all the tests I did, it seems it did worked perfectly! Thanks a lot @Dmitry S

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that it's not possible to combine insert, delete and select statements, I wouldn't recommend it anyway.

Okay, step by step...

> 1st. Insert the selected rows into a new table with the excatly same schema the query returns

Here a "trick" comes in handy. Execute your query but write

```
CREATE TABLE new_ping /*or whatever tablename*/ AS
SELECT ...
```

This will automatically create a table (and inserts the data), but this usually has to get adjusted, as there are no primary keys or indexes created and the datatypes sometimes don't fit. Your query would produce something like this (maybe some things are different when you execute it, like the engine or the character set, those settings depend on the default settings):

```
CREATE TABLE `new_ping` (
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupnum` mediumtext,
  `start_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` bigint(12) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

(you can get the above by querying `SHOW CREATE TABLE ping;`)

I suggest to always have a primary key in a table. It seems that `userid` and `groupnum` would be a good primary key. If you don't know you can also stick with an autoincrement column. Anyway, I'd adjust the table like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS new_ping;
CREATE TABLE `new_ping` (
  `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupnum` mediumtext,
  `start_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(12) DEFAULT NULL, /*bigint is certainly too big*/
  primary key (userid, groupnum)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Maybe you want to add an index on the other columns...

Now that you have your new create table statement drop the old table and recreate with above statement (or with your adjustments). I did so by adding the `DROP TABLE ...` statement above the `CREATE` statement.

Now you want to insert the data.

```
INSERT INTO new_ping (userid, groupnum, start_date, end_date, duration)
SELECT ... /*the query in your question*/
```

Next step...

> 2nd. Delete the selected rows, that were selected on the query and inserted into the new table.

I'm a little lost here. Which ones do you want to delete? The ones from the old table, right? Like in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c98c/2/0). But which ones exactly? The query from your questions just displays them as groups. Clear that up and write me comment, then I'll continue to answer...

Comment: Yes, delete the selected rows from the old table. Since I will be moving the groups to the new one, I wanna clean the old table. I tested your INSERT SELECT statement above, and worked perfectly. Thanks. On the select statement, I also need a condition, to only select the pings older than 60 seconds, cause I don't wanna select the pings of the users that are currently active and pinging to the system. @fancyPants

Comment: Like I said in my answer, this `Yes, delete the selected rows from the old table.` is not enough information. You display them in groups. Delete the groups basically means delete the whole table. Do you want to delete the first row or the last row of a group? Or which group of them? Or whatever? It's not clear!

Comment: And this `I also need a condition, to only select the pings older than 60 seconds` is also fairly easy. Please also have a try yourself. The reason why not more people answer, is, that this is not a "we do the whole work for you"-site. We are happy to help with problems, though.

Comment: Delete all rows from the pings table that were selected and grouped. On your query, yes, the hole table is selected, but since we will be adding a condition, to only group the rows, where the last ping < NOW() - 60 seconds, I don't want delete all the rows. For example if NOW = 100, and I got the pings 1,10,20,30,40,50,60 ... I won't be grouping these pings, and can't delete them from the pings table. When the last ping exceed 60 seconds, I will group these pings, select, insert into the new table, and delete them. is it possible? @fancyPants

Comment: I really tried to add the clause to only select the groups, where the last ping, exceed 60 seconds, but it don't seems to be working. I could add a clause to select pings, from NOW() - 60 seconds, but it's not really what I want to do. If the last ping, does not exceed 60 seconds, I don't wanna select any ping from this group, cause the user still pinging to the system. So, I only want select the pings from these groups, when the last ping, exceed, 60 seconds. It's kinda confusing, but I think the example above, will help illustrate it. I tried to add WHERE < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND ...

Comment: ... after )vars ... Tried to mess with the conditions ... IF( ping_timestamp - '@'prevTS >60 && ping_timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND, '@'groupnum +1, '@'groupnum ) ... And few others attempts failed. (added '@' on the sql above, cause Stack Overflow wouldn't allow me to notify you due the @'s) @fancyPants